# For Each Loop using Columns() returns full range

Tags: excel, vba

While answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378809/add-a-comment-to-every-cell-in-a-row-with-for-each-loop-vba-excel/69379131#69379131) I discovered that a For Each loop using Columns() will return the same range.

Take:

```
    Dim colrng As Range
    
    Set colrng = Columns(1)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each rng In colrng
        Debug.Print rng.Address, colrng.Address
    Next rng
```

It will return `Range("A:A")` for the value `rng.address`

If you run this, using `Range("A:A")` `rng` will be "A1", "A2", ...  as expected.

```
    Dim colrng As Range
    
    Set colrng = Range("A:A")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each rng In colrng
        Debug.Print rng.Address, colrng.Address
        If rng.Row = 5 Then 'No need to continue 
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rng
```

The same happens for `Rows()`

Anyone know what is happening behind the scenes here?

Comment: Add `.Cells`: `For Each rng in colrng.Cells`. Looping over columns means you're looping column-by-column, not over the cells in each column. Same for rows. Probably a dupe somehwere.

Comment: @BigBen Well, that's an easy one.

Comment: [Good answer that address the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51097214/9245853). Plus another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603480/9245853).